# Pressurized vessel in modelica

Tags: simulation, modelica, openmodelica, fluid-dynamics

I've been trying to create a pressurized vessel in openmodelica but i'm stuck.
The block i'm trying to build is a simple vessel for liquid pressurized by gas.

So two input ports (liquid input, gas input) and an output port for pressurized liquid outlet. The total volume of the vessel is constant. Looks simple but stuck with the duality gaz/liquid.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to provide any advice without your code. However, pressure vessels have been modelled in Modelica before and you could take inspiration from the following free libraries:

- [TRANSFORM](https://github.com/ORNL-Modelica/TRANSFORM-Library): e.g. models in `TRANSFORM.Fluid.Volumes`
- [ThermoPower](https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/ThermoPower): e.g. `ThermoPower.Water.Accumulator.mo`
- [Buildings](https://github.com/lbl-srg/modelica-buildings): e.g. `model Buildings.Fluid.Storage.ExpansionVessel.mo`